# To set ColorFilter in Android-Image-Cropper

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, cropper

I am using `Android-Image-Cropper by ArthurHub`.
I want to use `setColorFilter()` method but is not available in this library. So Can i have some solution for this or else any other option how can i set Color filters to `imageView`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: set t on that [ImageView](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/cropper/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper/CropImageView.java#L47)

Comment: there is no method in this library @pskink

Comment: Method is not defined in Android-Image-Cropper CropImageView class.Please check again

Comment: did you check yhe link i posted? this [link](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/cropper/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper/CropImageView.java#L47) - now simply call `setColorFilter()` method on that `mImageView`

Comment: Sir i have checked it .I cant call this method .because it is not available in this class or the link you have given above.

Comment: `public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {mImageView.setColorFilter(colorFilter);}` - is it really so hard to add such a new method in `CropImageView.java`?

Comment: No ,its not hard but i have to import a module then ,right now am using dependency for this

Comment: How to write in the file which is not writable .?

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper.git` - more [here](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/)